# view number of votes oneself has cast on questions and answers respectively

Tags: feature-request, activity-tab

On our own *Activity* page, on the *votes* tab we can quickly see the total number of *all*, *upvote*, *downvote*, *deletion*, *undelete*, *closure* and *reopen* votes we have cast. Is there a way to view the total number of votes we have cast on questions or answers respectively? (If there isn't, I'd like to have such a feature.)

Comment: At the bottom right of [your profile's "summary" tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2413201/armali?tab=summary), there is a section which seems to provide the stats you're asking for (or when you say votes, do you mean more than just up/down votes?)

Comment: @Matt: Silly me, you're right! How could I overlook that... Thank you! - Should I delete my question, or could it be useful to someone as blind as me?